# Sqoop import from redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, sqoop

Just as the title says, trying to move some data from `Redshift` to `S3` via `Sqoop`:

```
sqoop-import -Dmapreduce.job.user.classpath.first=true --connect "jdbc:redshift://redshiftinstance.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com:9999/stuffprd;database=ourDB;user=username;password=password;" --table ourtable -m 1 --as-avrodatafile --target-dir s3n://bucket/folder/folder1/
```

All drivers are in the proper folders however the error being throw is:

```
 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Got error creating database manager: java.io.IOException: No manager for connect string:
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you already have got the answer to this, but you need to add the following to your sqoop command:

`--driver com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver`

`--connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager`

Answer (score 0):

I can't help with the error but I recommend you *not* do it this way. Sqoop will try retrieve the table as `SELECT *` and all results will have to pass through the leader node. This will be much slower than using `UNLOAD` to export the data directly to S3 in parallel. You can then convert the unloaded text files to Avro using Sqoop.

Comment: Problem is we are pulling multiple other data sources using sqoop. Ideally, an Oozie workflow will kick off each sqoop job and then do the transformation in HIVE.  I'll have to see what my options, if any, there are to integrating  the UNLOAD to S3 with a scheduler.